# Facebook PHP SDK Graph API post to page not functioning properly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I'm trying to add a feature to my app that will post a status to a admin user's page timeline with the same detail as if they posted on Facebook.com.  The main feature I am focusing on is the link sharing and thumbnail images, like when you paste a link into your status and it auto-detects a thumbnail image, gives you a nice link, description, etc.  I have tireless read through other forums and the Graph API documents, and I keep running into problems with the post showing as the admin user, rather than the page.  Here is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appID,
  'secret' => $appSecret,
));

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    "scope" => 'publish_stream, read_insights, manage_pages, photo_upload, video_upload, create_note, manage_notifications'
));

$access_token   = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$fbpost = array();

$fbpost['access_token'] = $access_token;
$fbpost['message']      = $message;
$fbpost['link']         = $link;
$fbpost['description']  = $description;
$fbpost['caption']      = $caption;
$fbpost['picture']      = $fbimg;

$status = $facebook->api('/'.$pageID.'/feed', 'POST', $fbpost);
var_dump($status);
```

When I only post the $fbpost['message'] it correctly posts the status as the page, but when I add ANYTHING else it shows the post as the authenticated admin user instead of the page.  Very frustrating.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, when it posts as the admin user, it shows the links, picture etc as attachments and then has to authenticate through the app.  It is nothing like actually posting to the status timeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I keep running into problems with the post showing as the admin user, rather than the page.

Then get a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/), not a user access token for the admin user …

Comment: Thanks CBroe, didn't notice the additional access_token required on this page the first time I looked at it (there are too many Facebook docs!).  Since there's no good documentation about how to deal with this in PHP I'm going to post an answer as well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to CBroe for providing a [link to the Facebook docs on the page/app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/).  After checking that out, I came up with this PHP (since there is no good documentation in the PHP SDK for getting a page access token):

```
$user_token     = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$accounts       = $facebook->api('/me/accounts?access_token='.$user_token);
$account_token  = 0;
foreach ($accounts['data'] as $account) {
    if ($account['id'] == $_SESSION['facebook']) {
        $account_token = $account['access_token'];
    }
}

if ($account_token) {
    /// your page token code
} else {
    echo 'You must be an admin on this page!';
}
```