# Share Text To Facebook Wall

Tags: php, facebook

I have a textaera and a button, i enter some text in textarea and want to post it to facebook wall. I used this url 
http://facebook.com/share.php?u=http://test.com&t=test+share

but without passing url it is not woking.

Can anyone help me, i want only text to post on facebook wall

Answer (score 2):

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/post]
By using the above URL you can share your content over Facebook wall.
the link referral shows sharing content via HTTP,ANDROID-SDK,IOS-SDK,PHP- SDK,JAVA-SCRIPT-SDK.

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */

/* make the API call */
try {


 // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object


 $response = $fb->delete(
'/user-id/feed',
array (),
'{access-token}'


 );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) 
{
 echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();


 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {


echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;}$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here. i would suggest to use Facbook graph api and get the access token and then you are ready to post status on wall.

[Facebook PHP SDK Graph API post to page not functioning properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054915/facebook-php-sdk-graph-api-post-to-page-not-functioning-properly?rq=1)